# Can not connect to the Service /usr/local/bin/geckodriver in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
driver.get('http://www.python.org')
```

produces the following error:

> ERROR : Message: Can not connect to the Service /usr/local/bin/geckodriver

My settings:

- Mozilla Firefox 81.0
- OS => Parrot sec(linux)
- Python 3.8.6
- geckodriver 0.27.0

How can I fix this?

Comment: Probably Your gecko path '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver' is not added to system environment path. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path/46880071#46880071

Answer (score 0):

Move geckodriver file to /usr/bin and than change code as follow.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

Hope it helpful.
It works in my side.